# How to guide for getting a classic asp application working under IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

I am looking for a nice easy step by step "How To" guide for getting a classic asp application working under IIS 7.0.

It is on a 64 bit windows server 2008 machine if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Windows 2008 server? :)

Comment: Are you running 32 bit or 64 bit Windows, are you using any third party components - ServerObjects, Persits?

Comment: Nothing special apart from its using a SQL Server Express back end. 64 Bit Windows 2008...:)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

We've been moving some Classic ASP code to 64 bit Windows 2008. Here are some things we did or discovered along the way:

- Start off by hosting the application
  in a 'Classic' pipeline mode
  application pool. Once things are running just fine you can switch to 'Integrated Mode' should you need to leverage the features it offers at a later date.
- If your ASP application consumes any
  32 bit third party or in-house
  components you will need to configure the
  application pool to run in 32 bit
  mode. 32 bit DLL's won't load into a 64 bit process. You can configure this in the
  Advanced Settings of an application pool. Set `Enable 32-Bit Applications` to `True`.
- To force detailed error reporting by
  Classic ASP, open the ASP 'feature' page for the website then expand the
  `Debugging Properties` node. Set `Send Errors To Browser` to `True`.
- If your application uses parent paths
  you'll need to configure this in the ASP
  settings 'feature' page (same one as
  above). The setting is under the
  `Behaviour` node and is named
  `Enable Parent Paths`. The default setting is
  `False` just as with IIS6.
- The default anonymous account in IIS7
  is called `IUSR`. You can change this
  by opening the Authentication
  settings 'feature' page for the website and editing
  the `Anonymous Authentication`
  setting.
- Prefer to use Application Pool Identities for both the Application Pool and site Anonymous account: [Application Pool Identities](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/)

Comment: I have been looking all over that bit about `Anonymous Authentication` needing to be set.  I had done everything else except that and couldn't understand why my ASP application was trying to log in to the SQL Server as `IUSR` instead of the Application Pool Identity.

Comment: I thought Anonymous Authentication was a binary setting - It can be enabled or disabled. UNTIL, I looked at sidebar and saw an Edit option, which allows us to provide more settings for anonymous authentication

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a 5 year old thread,  but it is still relevant for those of us who have delayed migrating/upgrading old ASP apps.

There is something very important here that I was banging my head on for about 2 hours.   How in the world do you put an ASP app into an application pool, You cannot make ASP pages an application they just aren't compatible technologies.

Well in a DUHH moment,  I discovered that there is an application pool assigned to the overall site.  Just go to your Site under "Sites" and choose Basic Settings and assign an application pool.

All the rest of this is great info,  including registering your DLL's and I don't know if its in this thread,  but also making your ODBC connections 32 and 64 bit with the two different odbcad32.exe apps.

Thanks again,  (5 years late).

Answer (score 2):

Also note that if you need to register 32 bit dlls, while IIS is running in 32 bit mode, you should use \windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe dllname.dll.

Oh, and make sure you don't have server side debugging turned on for too long.  This will cause IIS to run in single threaded mode (and make it very slow).

Comment: I just found out recently that `regsvr32.exe` knows to do the "right thing" so you don't actually need to specify the 32 or 64 bit versions. Thought I'd share.