# Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 Migrating Website

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-2003-webserver

please try to give me some advice or solutions about migrating my application from win 2003 to win 2008(32bit). The problem was I keep getting the error 'ActiveX can't create object' error when starting an standard application. I can't get to login in my website maybe because it cannot create the COM+ application. When viewing the event log, there seems to be a warning coming from the DistributedCOM.

I've done the following so far in setting up the win 2008 server. Somehow I do the same when setting up in win 2003 which works fine.

- Configured website in IIS
- Installed VB6 DLL Application in COM+ services
- Checked the 'Allow IIS Intrinsic Properties' checkbox in COM+ services

Maybe you have encountered this so I'll try my luck and hope that I get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run your application in 32-Bit mode.

Try this:

IIS Manager->

->

Application Pools->

->

Advanced Settings):

"Enable 32-bit Applications" >> True

Also if it helps, more information and things you can try:

[How to guide for getting a classic asp application working under IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637326/how-to-guide-for-getting-a-classic-asp-application-working-under-iis-7-0)

Comment: Windows 2008 32-bit doesn't have that option in its IIS.