# MSDataShape {Class not registered error} in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, database-connection

I am trying to build a datagrid in Classic ASP. I have read a few articles here and there and am trying to use MSDataShape to implement this.

I have never worked with MSDataShape, so have absolutely no idea about it.

---

```
'Create the ADO Connection object. 
set oCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 

'--- Generate the connection string 
sCon = "Data Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Persist Security Info=False;" 
sCon = sCon & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("Northwind.mdb") 
oCon.ConnectionString = sCon 

'--- Specify that we will use the Data Shaping provider. 
oCon.Provider = "MSDataShape" 

'--- Open the connection 
oCon.Open
```

I get the following error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Service Components error '80040154' Class not
>   registered /DG/test.asp, line 39 –

Comment: here is my code.

'--- Create the ADO Connection object.
set oCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'--- Generate the connection string
sCon = "Data Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Persist Security Info=False;"
sCon = sCon & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("Northwind.mdb")
oCon.ConnectionString = sCon

'--- Specify that we will use the Data Shaping provider.
oCon.Provider = "MSDataShape"

'--- Open the connection
oCon.Open

I get the following error:


Microsoft OLE DB Service Components

 error '80040154' 

Class not registered 

/DG/test.asp, line 39

Comment: I tried my best to put this code in the main question, but it would not accept the code no matter what i tried. 4 spaces, > marks .... nothing seem to work.  Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the data provider you specified can't be found. In this case, 3.51 is a very old version of Jet. Try using the following:

```
sCon = "Data Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Also, if you're on a 64-bit OS, make sure you configure your application pool to run in [32-bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637326/249624).